# Получение времени отправки пакета с помощью библиотеки pcap

Tags: c++, c, pcap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью библиотеки pcap получить время отправки полученного пакета?
Если так, то определяется время захвата:

```
pcap_pkthdr header;
time_t local_tv_sec, local_usec;
local_tv_sec = header.ts.tv_sec;
local_usec = header.ts.tv_usec;
```

А нужно отправки. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: вообще говоря — никак, в ip пакете timestamp'а вообще нет, а в TCP обычно есть монотонный timestamp от произвольной точки во времени. И да, это не время получения, а время захвата пакета...

Comment: Исправил. Забыл уточнить предполагается отлов UDP-пакетов. Жаль, если никак.

Comment: с UDP тем более ни как — там заголовок ещё легче... только если какой-то прикладной протокол сам вставляет timestamp...